# Decide if f(X) is irreducible in the following rings

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $$f(X) = 78X^3 + 174X^2 − 116 ∈ Z[X]$$

My question is to decide if $f(X)$ is irreducible in $Z[X], Q[X] and R[X]$

I have tried finding a prime number 29, and to fulfil the Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion

1)  $29$ is a common factor of $-116$ and $174$ in $Z$;

2) $29^2 = 841$ is not a factor of $-116$ in $Z$

3) $29$ is not a factor of $78$.

So that its enough to show $f(X)$ is irreducible in $Q[X]$.

And for $R[X]$ there should be no root as a integers so its should be irreducible but are there any way i can prove there really not integers root? And i also getting stuck in how to check with $Z[X]$, are there anything needed from the above calculation or is it something new?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add further tags, e.g. abstract-algebra

Comment: For $f(X)$ to be irreducible in $Bbb Q[X]$, it must have a linear factor of the form $ax+b$, where $a \vert 39$ and $b \vert 58$.

Comment: @Robert Not true, e.g.  $\ (78x-1)(x-116).\,$ But OP already used Eisenstein to show  irreducibility over $\,\Bbb Q.\ \ $

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You've shown there are no integers as roots because you've shown its irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ Are you asking how to show that it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Dione Hint: in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ these are both reducible $\,2^2,\  2x,\,$ being products of nonzero nonunits. See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2188830/242)

Comment: Those are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.  They cannot be factored into a product of non constant polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Dione That definition works only when the coef ring is a *field* - see the link I gave in my prior comment.

Comment: Yes, I see now.  I didn't know the definition was different if the underlying ring is not a field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem is more boring now though haha.

Answer (score 1):

Every cubic polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root and therefore it is reducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

It is also reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, since it is equal to $2\times(39x^3+87x^2-58)$.

Comment: How are you concluding that it's reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ from that factorization?  This cannot be correct because it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: $2$ is a unit (i.e., a divisor of $1$) in $\Bbb Q$ but not in $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

One (other) way to show that it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ is to notice that $f(0) < 0$ and $f(1) >0$.  Hence, there must be a root between in $(0,1)$